# How to convert SELinux mypol.te file to semanage commands for a script

Tags: selinux

Have setup a special logging directory for MySQL logs. This required me to run the command

```
grep mysqld /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
```

a number of times to authorize MySQL to search, open, write etc in the MySQL log directory.

The final result was a `mypol.te` file that looks like this:

```
module mypol 1.0;

require {
    type mysqld_log_t;
    type mysqld_t;
    class dir { write search read remove_name open add_name };
}

#============= mysqld_t ==============
allow mysqld_t mysqld_log_t:dir open;
#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy

allow mysqld_t mysqld_log_t:dir { write remove_name search read add_name };
```

However I want to use the `semanage` command in a script to do this automatically in future builds.

Wondering how I can convert the above `mypol.te` into a set of `semanage` commands?

Comment: What is your reason to use `semanage` for this instead of compiling and loading the resulting se-module?

Comment: My bash script installs MySQL, creates the logging directory, creates MySQL users, sets permissions, and does some basic SELinux permissions that I have been able to work out, as well as other sundry tasks.

It will be much more efficient if I can do everything in the one script rather than doing some things in a script and then have to copy a policy file to the server as well.

Comment: continuing from last comment:

From the Fedora SELinux documentation I have been able to work out certain commands that I have needed to do such as:
`code` semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_log_t '/var/log/mysql(/.*)?' `code`

If there is a way to add permissions for searching etc, everything will be in a single script.

Comment: I still do not understand. I hope you do these installation tasks by building a RPM. So it would not be a big problem to put into that RPM a policy file and install that via post-install-script (the same post install will install your users, while creating directories and settings permissions is a typical rpm-installation-task...). Apart from I do not think that there is a general solution for your problem, since - according to the man-page - semanage handles only a subset of what policies can do.

Comment: Your suggestion to package everything up in an RPM is interesting.
I have always found RPM how to documentation very poor as it makes so many assumptions.
Any references for how I would turn my pot pourri of bash scripts into RPMs would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - this is not right on target, but you may achieve your goal by building a RPM. Since you can write shell-scripts, you will not have a problem with RPMs.

Your target is to install mySQL and do some post-installation tasks like addings users, and adding a SELinux-policy.

I will try to outline a generic receipe. You can find a better overview about building rpms [here](http://www.redhat.com/promo/summit/2008/downloads/pdf/Wednesday_130pm_Tom_Callaway_OSS.pdf).

1. Grab your flavour of mySQL from the [mirror of mysql-sources](http://mirror.services.wisc.edu/mysql/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/) - go for the src.rpm version, download it.
2. install that src.rpm - this will give you a SPEC-file to start with (and it will install the sources for mySQL as well - ready for compilation)
3. Include your SEPolicy-file into the source-section
4. In the %configure Section you can set your specific configure-options - like you would do on a
5. Modify the %build section so that "your" directories get created there, also compile your SEPolicy at that point
6. Install the needed users/groups in the %post-section - do not forget the case where these may already be installed - in the %post-section do the activation of the compiled SELinux-policy
7. Include the built Module in the %install - section, as well as "your" special directories

Once you have made your first RPM - the next ones will be easy. But perhaps you should make this a question of its own. I did not find a good one on UL.

Comment: Thank you. I will give RPM a try. The Tom Callaway slides give me new hope.